# Theme changed event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

Ive built a Winforms RadForms application with VB.Net. The application contains several forms that contains several rad controls. The theme is changed by clicking a button. But it takes around 3-4 seconds for the theme to change. Now what I want to achieve is the application must show a message box with the message- "Theme Changed" when the theme has changed. I was wondering if there are any events that can be fired during a theme change and found one event named "ThemeNameChanged".  I set it up like this:

> Private Sub theme_changed (source as Object, args As ThemeNameChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.ThemeNameChanged
> Msgbox("Theme Changed")
> End Sub

Then I switch the theme with the click of a button:

> Private sub Button1_Click(...) Handles Button1.Click   ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeName = "TelerikMetroBlue"
> End Sub

But when click Button1 the theme changes but the message is not displayed once the theme has changed. So How Do I dsiplay a message when the theme has changed?

Comment: `ThemeNameCahngedEventArgs` this wont compile... `ThemeNameChangedEventArgs` that's what it should be. Also you don't have a routine name either.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ thanks for the correction. I've now edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the ThemeResolutionService.**ApplicationThemeName** property will style the entire application with the newly applied theme. However, in order to detect the theme changing in this case the ThemeResolutionService offers the **ApplicationThemeChanged** event:

```
    Sub New() 
    InitializeComponent()

    AddHandler ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeChanged, AddressOf ThemeResolutionService_ApplicationThemeChanged

End Sub
Private Sub RadButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton1.Click
    ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeName = "Fluent"
End Sub

Private Sub RadButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton2.Click
    ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeName = "FluentDark"
End Sub

Private Sub ThemeResolutionService_ApplicationThemeChanged(sender As Object, args As ThemeChangedEventArgs)
    RadMessageBox.Show("Theme changed " & ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeName)
End Sub
```